# How to hide (distracting) usernames on cards

Tags: trello, trello-cards

How do I hide my username (which is in Bold) from every comment I post on a Trello card?

It looks like a very distracting heading of every comment and not needed at all for me.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install [Stylish](https://userstyles.org/)
2. Install [this style](https://userstyles.org/styles/150388/trello-hide-comment-names)
3. Done!

Answer (score 0):

Trelo will, by default, create a heading for each comment with the name of the commenter.

If you need to add content to a card without having your name separate out each post, then may I suggest adding the "comment" into the description section as a new line.  That might give you the ability to *comment* without your name headlining each entry.